# Add database to a project in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, lucene.net

We are making a search engine in visual studio 2013 and we are writing the code in C#. Our problem is that we have a database and we want to search in it. So far we only have a file calles Default.aspx.cs which works as our databse. How can we do so that our project will search in a database rather that SampleData?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add all existing records to Lucene search index
        LuceneSearch.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(SampleDataRepository.GetAll());

        // todo: add record to database...


        // add record to Lucene search index
        LuceneSearch.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new SampleData { Id = 1, Name = "SomeName 0", Description = "SomeDescription" });
        LuceneSearch.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new SampleData { Id = 2, Name = "SomeName 1", Description = "SomeDescription" });
        LuceneSearch.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new SampleData { Id = 3, Name = "SomeName 2", Description = "SomeDescription" });
        LuceneSearch.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new SampleData { Id = 4, Name = "Annet navn", Description = "SomeDescription" });
        LuceneSearch.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new SampleData { Id = 4, Name = "Annet navn og beskrivelse", Description = "annet" });
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the question is how to search a database using lucene.net? The title of the question looks like another question.

Answer (score 1):

[Give this a shot](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application):

> Using MVC, Entity Framework, and ASP.NET Scaffolding, you can create a
>   web application that provides an interface to an existing database.
>   This tutorial series shows you how to automatically generate code that
>   enables users to display, edit, create, and delete data that resides
>   in a database table. The generated code corresponds to the columns in
>   the database table.
>
> This part of the series focuses on creating the web application, and
>   generating the data models based on your database tables.

The link above provides a walkthrough for adding a database to an MVC project

[This](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part4) one also seems a little more aimed towards beginners, if the first one was a bit too complex:

> This is a beginner tutorial that introduces the basics of ASP.NET MVC.
>   You’ll create a simple web application that reads and writes from a
>   database. Visit the ASP.NET MVC learning center to find other ASP.NET
>   MVC tutorials and samples.